# Trying to run hp-toolbox from HPLIP but gives python errors

Tags: python, hp

I am trying to get my HP Deskjet F2280 printer running, I've Googled that I need HPLIP to print anything with HP printers on Linux but after I installed and ran HPLIP-toolbox from KDE it doesn't let me. I've tried to run it from the terminal and it returns these Python errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hp-toolbox", line 40, in <module>
    from base import status, tui, module
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/status.py", line 31, in <module>
    import xml.parsers.expat as expat
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt
```

I have no idea what to do now, I'm afraid that a bug has occurred because of something I have done to my system as I've been installing and changing Python related things and I wasn't able to use mypaint either.

Comment: Have you tried getting your printer working through the `system-config-printer` application? is it a CUPS configuration tool that comes provided with Ubuntu and it automatically setup my HP ENVY 5530 series printer using HPLIP.

Comment: I still get python errors. I think it's python problem.... http://pastebin.com/us8xhPFH

Comment: Strange, maybe try reinstalling python with: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python`. If that doesn't work you may want to try reinstalling `libpython2.7-stdlib` as that will replace the `pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so` file which may to causing this issue.

Comment: It didn't work. But... You know, i've found solution... But thanks for your help, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out what was wrong, `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so` was using the shared library `/usr/local/lib/libexpat.so.1` when it should have been using `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1` and simply renaming or removing `/usr/local/lib/libexpat.so.1` solved the issues with python.

A source can be found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2094005&p=12436009#post12436009)

Comment: So you had libexpat files in /usr/local/lib and renaming them fixed the issues with python?

Comment: Just added something to the name so its not recognized (like .backup as the ChoneZone did or something else) by pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so - it was using shared lib - /usr/local/lib/libexpat.so.1, and now it is using /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1. I'm not programming in python, but i think libexpat.so.1 from usr/local/lib didn't fit as a shared lib for pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so